# Unity - Sprite disappears completely when just a part of it is outside the camera's FOV

Tags: unity, sprites, camera, frustum-culling

I'm making a game in Unity, and when the player walks past a sprite, the sprite disappears, and when the player walks back toward it, it reappears. You can see a video of the problem here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgLN3m94tBo

I've also included my camera script below if anyone wants to check that out. Any help on this matter would be more than appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Camera : MonoBehaviour {

private Transform target;

private float minX = 7.99f;
private float minY = -19.09f;


public float maxX, maxY;

void Start()
{
    target = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
}

void LateUpdate()
{

    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(target.position.x, minX, maxX), Mathf.Clamp(target.position.y, minY, maxY), transform.position.z);
}
}
```

Here's a screenshot of my camera's settings

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your follow script. Post a screenshot of the settings of the Camera itself. This kind of thing is usually due to something being misconfigured in the camera settings.

Comment: I'll try to post a screenshot, but everything is very basic. I didn't adjust the camera or anything. Could it have something to do with frustum culling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue had to do with a plugin I was using to import my .tmx file into Unity. I switched to Tiled2Unity and the problem no longer persists.